# Job batch as400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'm currently trying to run a program in Batch via wrkjobscde. 
the program starts normally but when I do a wrkactjob, I see it go into dspw and stay like this for hours before being interrupted by qsys.
however, when I launch it in interactive mode, it runs very well in a few minutes.
Do you please have any explanation to that please?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question is unfortunately unclear. Please edit your question and clarify as we are unable to help you at this stage.

Comment: Actually, it makes sense to me. Please don't close it.

Comment: For those who are not familiar with the IBM i operating system, this makes perfect sense. Do not close this! It had a bad tag.

Comment: Now for @aicha04, are you sure you are looking at the correct job in WRKACTJOB? I would not expect a BCH job to allow that as it can not attach a display file. Instead I would expect it to crash out with a RNQ1216 when it tried to open the display file.

Comment: There, reopened it...

Comment: You are going to have to show us the CL code. DSPW means it is waiting on the display. Also, show us the WRKACTJOB screen. Make sure the `Type` column is on the screen.

Comment: the problem is rather the sqlrpgle and not the CL. I did the test by commenting the first query and there the program works in batch.
as the two queries point to the same file I feel that this is where it stuck.
But I still do not understand why it works well in interactive and not in batch. what are the differences between the two modes?

Comment: Sorry it's TIMW and not DSPW but still the same problem :(

Comment: No, not the same problem. It is caused by different things. TIMW is caused by a call to DLYJOB or the sleep() API. Look for a call to QCMDEXC (which can be used to execute DLYJOB) or a call to sleep() or a procedure with an external procedure name of 'sleep'.

Comment: how can I look for the call?

Comment: in the source of the program that is waiting.

Comment: Show us what you removed to make the program work.

Answer (score 2):

DSPW means that a screen has popped up waiting for human interaction. Run the program interactively and if any screen pops up, you either can't run it in batch or you will have to modify the program so that it will run in batch. Without seeing the code, I can't help much more, but that is where I would start.

Comment: the program executes two sql queries. when it is in batch, it executes well the first and then it passes in dspw.
When it's interactive, it works normally and I do not have any windows that pop up

Comment: @aicha04 So you are saying that the program has no display file?

Comment: @MikeWills its an sqlrpgle programm that is called in my CL

Comment: the problem is rather the sqlrpgle and not the CL. I did the test by commenting the first query and there the program works in batch.
as the two queries point to the same file I feel that this is where it stuck.
But I still do not understand why it works well in interactive and not in batch. what are the differences between the two modes?